# android code to click button multiple times using for loop

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick

can any 1 give me example to perform onClick on button for multiple times when user clicked for 1 time. when i click on button 1 time it should automatically click after delay of 5 seconds for 100 times. how to perform that.
This is my sample code

```
mUnlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //It should be already ensured that this mSelectedLock is something user is authorized to access
                    if (mSelectedLock.unlock("RANDOM")) {
                        mUnlock.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mUnlock.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                mUnlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        }, 5000);


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to unlock.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: use Handle for delay and disable button click

Comment: buttton.performClick();

Comment: i can disable button. but i need to perform onclick operation for 100 times

Comment: you cant access to  UI element  in another thread ....

Answer (score 1):

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {actionToBeDone();startLoop(0);}

```
private void startLoop(final int i) {
    if(i!=100) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("i",""+i);
                actionToBeDone();
                startLoop(i+1);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}

private void actionToBeDone() {
    //enter actions you want to be done
    Log.e("actionToBeDone","Button Action");
}
```

Comment: call these 2 functions in your onclick

Comment: make it 5000 instead of 2000

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;    
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
      if(count < 100){
          mUnlock.performClick();
      }
   }
}, 0, 5000);
```

5000 is the time in miliseconds you can +/- from here.